# Inserting polygon centroids into an additional column in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, postgis-1.5

I'm trying to calculate the x and y centroids for a table using [ST_Centroid](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Centroid.html). The documentation says that it returns the geometric center of a geometry. I first made a column `X`:

```
ALTER TABLE "test_table" ADD X double precision;
```

and was then planning on storing the x component of the centroid there. My code to calculate the centroid is as follows:

```
select
  ST_Centroid(a.the_geom) 
FROM 
  "test_table" AS a
```

However this query returns the following result which I don't understand:

```
"01010000006BAEC2FBDFC61E415B3E9E2946520541"
"0101000000E6ABADEBFEC51E4102E9A95858520541"
"01010000003233333321C61E410BD7A37061520541"
"0101000000F710787300C61E4177C8C783D94E0541"
```

My second problem with this approach is trying to store the result. When I tried to insert this result into Column `X` I could not figure out the correct syntax. What I tried using was:

```
INSERT INTO "test_table" (X)
VALUES ( ST_Centroid(a.the_geom) ),
FROM "test_table" AS a
```

and also

```
INSERT INTO "test_table" (X)
VALUES ( SELECT ST_Centroid(a.the_geom) 
FROM "test_table" AS a)
```

but neither of these work.

My two very basic questions are (1) what is the value being returned by `ST_Centroid`, and (2) how I can I insert the result into an existing table?

Comment: I tried underdark's solution, or a variation thereof: ALTER TABLE parcels2012_2 ADD x double precision; ALTER TABLE parcels2012_2 ADD y double precision; UPDATE parcels2012_2 SET x = ST_X(ST_PointOnSurface(the_geom)); UPDATE parcels2012_2 SET y = ST_Y(ST_PointOnSurface(the_geom)); However, I get an error: NOTICE: TopologyException: side location conflict at -80.206658911211804 26.809848924607316 ERROR: GEOS pointonsurface() threw an error! Any ideas? I can easily return single points, and even small subsets, but it can't handle all 625,000 polygons in one command.

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.

Comment: I recommend that you ask a new Question if your research indicates that it has not already been answered here or elsewhere.

Comment: It has been answered (2 years ago) and with the correct answer marked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want x and y columns:

```
ALTER TABLE "test_table" ADD x double precision;
ALTER TABLE "test_table" ADD y double precision;
UPDATE "test_table" SET x = ST_X(ST_Centroid(the_geom));
UPDATE "test_table" SET y = ST_Y(ST_Centroid(the_geom));
```

If you rather want a geometry column (adjust schema name and CRS to fit your needs):

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('test_schema','test_table','centroid_geom',4326,'POINT',2);
UPDATE "test_table" SET centroid_geom = ST_Centroid(the_geom);
```

Answer (score 9):

You must use [ST_X function](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_X.html).

Assuming that you want to fill a column of a table that already has a geometry column with the x coordinate of the centroid you can use something like:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET x = ST_X(ST_Centroid(the_geom));
```

If you need something different post the complete structure of the table if you need more accurate help.

Answer (score 4):

It is a Geometry (a Point in fact). What you are seeing is the text representation of the point as Well Known Binary (WKB) for debugging purposes you'd probably want well known text (WKT) (see https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OpenGISWKBWKT),

```
select
  ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(a.the_geom) )
FROM 
  "test_table" AS a
```

Will show what you want to see.

To do the addition you need a geometry column rather than a double. For this you need to use [addGeometryColumn](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html) which handles all the bookkeeping needed for you (things like adding the column to the geometry columns metadata etc).

Comment: Thanks @iant. Is there a way of accessing each element that returns? Something like `ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(a.the_geom),1)` so that I can get `x` and `y` separately. I do have a column called ` the_geom geometry` but I assume that is the default geometry of each element.

Comment: Just found it - I used `ST_X(ST_Centroid(a.the_geom))` and `ST_Y(ST_Centroid(a.the_geom))`